# Find path of FIXED length through a 2D array which gives maximum sum

Tags: java, recursion, path, multidimensional-array, maze

I have looked through many forum codes which are similar to this question, but I am still unable to solve my question. Basically, given a 2D square array of size n, filled with integers within [-100,100], I have to find the maximum sum, given that the path is of length 10. This is done starting from a certain given grid (denoted by *). It is illegal to visit a same grid twice.

A sample test case would be:

```
-55  34 -51  35  1
-76  26  69  61  *
 68  98  17  85  81
-27 -69  49  42  83
-10  31  44  75 -41
```

Would produce a maximum sum of `637`. 
Denoted by the path: `61 69 26 98 17 85 81 83 42 75`

If I'm not wrong, the problem with my code is about marking the grids that I have visited before. But I don't know how to solve that..

Below is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

class Maze
{
static int[][] matrix;
static int counter = 0;
static int size = 0;
static int maximum = -100000;
static int result = -1000000;
static int currMax; 
static int topMax, downMax, leftMax, rightMax;

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    size = sc.nextInt();
    matrix = new int[size][size];
    int xcord = 0;
    int ycord = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<size; j++){
            if (sc.hasNextInt()){
                int util = sc.nextInt();
                matrix[i][j] = util;
            }
            else{
                String utilStr = sc.next();
                xcord = i;
                ycord = j;
                matrix[i][j] = -2000;
            }
        }
    }
    result = 2000 + findMax(xcord, ycord);
    System.out.println(result);
}

static int findMax(int currx, int curry){
    if (counter >= 9){
            return matrix[currx][curry];
    }
    else {
        counter = counter+1;

        System.out.println("Round: "+counter);
        System.out.println("currx: "+currx+" curry: "+curry);
        int temp = matrix[currx][curry];
        matrix[currx][curry] = -2000;

        downMax = -10000; //To reset it for comparison
        if (currx+1 != size && matrix[currx+1][curry] == -2000){
        downMax = findMax(currx+1,curry);
        }
        rightMax = -10000;
        if (curry+1 != size && matrix[currx][curry+1] == -2000){
        rightMax =  findMax(currx,curry+1);
        }
        topMax = -10000;
        if (currx-1 >=0 && matrix[currx-1][curry] == -2000){
        topMax =  findMax(currx-1,curry);
        }
        leftMax = -10000;
        if (curry-1 >= 0 && matrix[currx][curry-1] == -2000){
        leftMax =  findMax(currx,curry-1);
        }

        matrix[currx][curry] = temp;

        currMax = Math.max(downMax,rightMax);
        currMax = Math.max(currMax, topMax);
        currMax = Math.max(currMax, leftMax);

        maximum = currMax + temp;
        return maximum;
        }
}
```

}

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Here are a couple of hints: you are not doing anything to flag where you have already visited. If you do that it will also help you get rid of the rather arbitrary "2000" flag. Also, you are never incrementing the `counter` so once you finished one traversal, it remains at 9. I suggest passing the current depth as a parameter rather than a static field.

Comment: Thank you for reply! After passing the depth as a parameter, I managed to complete the recursion. However, my marking of visited grids still does not work.

I used matrix[currx][curry] = -5000 to mark the nodes that I have passed and subsequently, set the value back. Why does it not work?

Comment: It doesn't because there are many potential paths that might give you your desired answer, but when you flag one field with -5000 this cell is tainted for all other potential paths.

Comment: Oh, but I am changing the value back within the same recursion with matrix[currx][curry] = temp, so wouldn't that restore the value (thus opening up the path again?). Sorry, I don't quite get it. Any suggestions on how to mark the paths?

Comment: You're changing it back **after** all the recursion. So all deeper recursion levels still see the flag.

Comment: Oh okay I get it now. Thanks for your prompt reply!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution and explanations:

```java
public static int MAX_DEPTH = 10;

static Integer[][] matrix;
static Coord[] directions = {
    new Coord(-1, 0),
    new Coord(1, 0),
    new Coord(0, -1),
    new Coord(0, 1)
};

private static class Coord {
    int row;
    int col;

    private Coord(int row, int col) {
        this.col = col;
        this.row = row;
    }

    private Coord newPosition(Coord relative) {
        return new Coord(row + relative.row, col + relative.col);
    }
}
```

First, I define the matrix as a 2D array of `Integer` rather than int. This makes it easy to mark visited positions and the "*" position using `null`. It's just a convenience.

I am using a small inner class `Coord` to help me with coordinate calculations. As you see, I have created a static array of all the directions I'll need to explore at every step, as this will simplify the recursive method, and prevent unneeded repetitions of code that may later need fixing in four different places.

```java
private static Coord fillMatrix() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int size = sc.nextInt();
    matrix = new Integer[size][size];
    Coord coord = new Coord(0, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
                int util = sc.nextInt();
                matrix[i][j] = util;
            } else {
                sc.next();
                coord.row = i;
                coord.col = j;
                matrix[i][j] = null;
            }
        }
    }
    sc.close();
    return coord;
}
```

My `fillMatrix` method fills the matrix and returns the coordinate of the "*" (or rather, the non-integer in the input). It's based on yours, with these notes:

- I mark the "*" place in the matrix with null.
- You should close every Scanner you open.
- There is no need to define a variable to store the value of scanning the "*", as we don't use it. Java allows calling methods that return a value without assigning that value anywhere.

```java
    private static boolean isLegalPosition(Coord position) {

        if ( position.row < 0 || position.row >= matrix.length ) {
            return false;
        }

        if ( position.col < 0 || position.col >= matrix[0].length ) {
            return false;
        }

        return matrix[position.row][position.col] != null;
    }
```

Given a position in the matrix, this method checks if it is legal - if it is within the boundaries of the arrays (we have to assume at least one row exists), and if it is not marked with a `null` (visited/start).

Now we come to the recursive method itself. You pass it the current depth and the current accumulated sum, in addition, of course, to the current position from which it should start looking. This position is assumed to already be marked with null.

```java
    private static Integer findMax(Coord currPosition, int currDepth,
            int currSum) {

        // Recursion end: if we reached a depth of 10, we have the maximum at
        // the current position

        if (currDepth == MAX_DEPTH) {
            return currSum;
        }

        // Find the greatest number in all four directions. We start with an
        // unknown Max value.

        Integer currMax = null;
        for (Coord direction : directions) {

            Coord newPos = currPosition.newPosition(direction);

            // If the position is legal (inside the matrix and not visited),
            // explore it by adding depth, and adding the current matrix
            // value to the accumulated.
            if (isLegalPosition(newPos)) {

                // Save the value at the new position, and mark it as visited.
                int matrixValue = matrix[newPos.row][newPos.col];
                matrix[newPos.row][newPos.col] = null;

                Integer newMax = findMax(newPos, currDepth + 1, currSum + matrixValue);

                // Restore the value in the current matrix position so that
                // upper level recursions don't think it's visited.
                matrix[newPos.row][newPos.col] = matrixValue;

                // Calculate the new max. If this is the first legal path, use
                // it. Otherwise check which one is greater.
                if (newMax != null) {
                    currMax = (currMax == null) ? newMax
                            : (newMax > currMax ? newMax : currMax);
                }
            }
        }

        return currMax;
    }
```

As you can see, I keep a variable named `currMax`, which starts out as `null`. It will end up being the max among all numbers collected from the four directions. But it may happen that all four directions could not reach depth 10 because they run into the wall and visited positions. In that case, they will return null, and if this happens in all four directions, we return currMax - which is `null` - as well.

If we do find a legal path in any of the directions, we'll update `currMax` with it (if it's greater than it, of course).

At each step, before we go deeper into the recursion, we mark the new position with null to show it was visited, but take care to restore it as soon as we finish with it. Otherwise the position will stay marked for the visit of the next direction, for which it is not supposed to be considered `visited`.

The call to the recursion from `main`, after filling the matrix, of course, looks like this:

```java
Integer maxVal = findMax(startCoord, 0, 0);
```

That is, we pass it the coordinates of the "*", start at the depth of 0, and with an accumulated sum of 0. Why 0 and not -2000? Because we are not actually comparing this number with anything. Any path we go through which actually gets to depth 10 will return the actual sum of the positions it has traversed, added to this zero, whether this sum is negative or positive. Any path that doesn't end up at depth 10 will return null. So no need for artificial values.

Comment: Thank you for your super detailed explanation! I managed to solve the question.

Comment: +1 for compactness and small memory footprint. I guess the conditions in isLegalPosition() should be  
    if (position.row == matrix.length || position.row<0) { 
        return false; 
    }

Comment: @Oncaphillis Oh, apparently when one uses <pre><code> as code formatting, one needs to escape the "<" signs. That caused my conditions to look really bad though of course I tested this code before posting.

Answer (score 0):

How about this. The current search path is stored in a Stack container which helps to identify positions we've already seen. On every recursion level we peek for the fields S/N/W/E of the current position and set currMax to the current sum if the current stack size == 11 (start field plus the rest).

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;



class Coord {
    public Coord(int i,int j) {
        this.i=i;
        this.j=j;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return ((Coord)o).i == i && ((Coord)o).j == j;
    }

    public int i;
    public int j;
};

class Main {
    static int[][] matrix;
    static int counter = 0;
    static int size = 0;
    static int currMax=-2000; 
    static Stack<Coord> currStack = new Stack<Coord>();


    public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        FileInputStream f=new FileInputStream(new File("/home/bla/bla.txt"));
        Stack<Coord> s = new Stack<Coord> ();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
        size = sc.nextInt();

        matrix = new int[size][size];
        int xcord = 0;
        int ycord = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<size; j++){
                if (sc.hasNextInt()){
                    int util = sc.nextInt();
                    matrix[i][j] = util;
                }
                else{
                    String utilStr = sc.next();
                    s.push(new Coord(i,j));
                }
            }
        }

        int sum=0;
        System.out.println(findMax(s,sum));

        Iterator<Coord> i=currStack.iterator();
        int ss=0;
        while(i.hasNext()) {
            Coord c = i.next();
            System.out.println(c.i+" "+c.j+" "+matrix[c.i][c.j]);
            ss+=matrix[c.i][c.j];

        }
        System.out.println("<"+ss+">");

    }

    static int findMax(Stack<Coord> s,int sum){

        // TOP
        if(s.lastElement().i > 0    && (s.search(new Coord(s.lastElement().i-1,s.lastElement().j  ))==-1) ) {
            Stack<Coord> nstack = (Stack<Coord>)s.clone();
            nstack.push(new Coord(s.lastElement().i-1,s.lastElement().j  ));
            int nsum = sum + matrix[nstack.lastElement().i][nstack.lastElement().j];
            if(nstack.size()<11) {
                nsum=findMax(nstack,nsum);
            }
            else {
                if(nsum > currMax) {
                    currMax   = nsum;
                    currStack = nstack;
                }
            }
        }
        // BOTTOM
        if(s.lastElement().i+1 < matrix.length && (s.search(new Coord(s.lastElement().i+1,s.lastElement().j  ))==-1) ) {
            Stack<Coord> nstack = (Stack<Coord>)s.clone();
            nstack.push(new Coord(s.lastElement().i+1,s.lastElement().j  ));            
            int nsum = sum + matrix[nstack.lastElement().i][nstack.lastElement().j];
            if(nstack.size()<11) {
                nsum = findMax(nstack,nsum);
            }
            else {
                if(nsum>currMax) {
                    currMax   = nsum;
                    currStack = nstack;
                }
            }
        }
        // LEFT
        if(s.lastElement().j > 0   && (s.search(new Coord(s.lastElement().i  ,s.lastElement().j-1))==-1) ) {
            Stack<Coord> nstack = (Stack<Coord>)s.clone();
            nstack.push(new Coord(s.lastElement().i  ,s.lastElement().j-1));
            int nsum = sum + matrix[nstack.lastElement().i][nstack.lastElement().j];
            if(nstack.size()<11) {
                nsum = findMax(nstack,nsum);
            }
            else {
                if(nsum>currMax) {
                    currMax   = nsum;
                    currStack = nstack;
                }
            }
        }

        // RIGHT
        if(s.lastElement().j+1 < matrix[0].length && (s.search(new Coord(s.lastElement().i  ,s.lastElement().j+1))==-1) ) {
            Stack<Coord> nstack = (Stack<Coord>)s.clone();
            nstack.push(new Coord(s.lastElement().i  ,s.lastElement().j+1));
            int nsum = sum +matrix[nstack.lastElement().i][nstack.lastElement().j];
            if(nstack.size()<11) {
                nsum = findMax(nstack,nsum);
            }
            else {
                if(nsum>currMax) {
                    currMax   = nsum;
                    currStack = nstack;
                }
            }
        }
        return currMax;
    }
}
```